# Input search box transition (width) is not smooth

Tags: css, reactjs, css-transitions

I am trying to expand the input search box on focus and compress it to its original state on loosing focus from search box. I am able to achieve the same using css transition. But some times i see the transition not happening smoothly as shown in examples. Is there any best way to achieve the same? or any suggestions to my code to achieve smoothness.

While expanding it is causing the sibling components also re-render because it is expanding its with.

React Code:

```
 <div className="header" style={{ width: "420px"}} ref={(searchHeader) => { this._searchHeader = searchHeader }}>
      <label className="label">{"Search here"}</label>
      <div className="SearchBox">
           <input className="input" spellCheck={false} onFocus={this.onFocus} onBlur={this.onBlur} />
           <div className="search-icon">
                <span className="Search-icon" />
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>




private onFocus = (): void => {
        if (this._searchHeader) {
            this._searchHeader.style.width = "1000px";
        }
    }

    private onBlur = (): void => {
        if (this._searchHeader) {
            this._searchHeader.style.width = "420px";
        }
    }
```

CSS:

```
.label{
        width: 110px;
        padding-top: 6px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.header {
        display: flex;
        align-items: stretch;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        -webkit-transition: width 2s linear; /* Safari*/
        transition: width 2s linear;
}

.input{
        align-self: stretch;
        min-width: 200px;
        padding: 0 6px;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to increase the width of searchHeader or input box on focus?

Comment: Search Header    when input box gets focued

Comment: I would say, probably not a good idea to resize searchHeader just to resize your input box unless you have no other option because as you mentioned child elements will rerender. I will try to mock the code you have here unless you have fiddle or jsbin already.

Comment: The problem is the change in width is causing re rendering of sibling components. That is why the smoothness is gone. Any way to stop re rendering of sibling components.

Comment: I would update the `width` value in the state in onFocus and onBlur and use the value in render. I would NOT do this `this._searchHeader.style.width = "1000px";`

Answer (score 0):

I have created a codebin to fix your issue. Please check if this works for you.

Please don't use refs, instead use state.

```
  onFocus() {
    // console.log('OnFocus', this);
    this.setState({
      isFocused: true
    })
  }

  onBlur() {
    // console.log('onBlur', this);
    this.setState({
      isFocused: false
    })
  }
```

https://codepen.io/Harsh89/pen/GQQPxK?editors=1111